# How to replace emoji to word in a text?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Imagine I have a text like this?

```
text = "game is on  "
```

How can I convert the emojis in the text to words?

Here what I've tried and this code below converts the emoji to word but how can I replace it in place of emoji in the original text. I couldn't figure it out.

```
import emot
[emot.emoji(i).get('mean').replace(':','').replace('_',' ').replace('-',' ') for i in text.split()]
```

Expected Output:

```
game is on fire fire
```

I've come across these two python modules
[`Emoji`](https://github.com/carpedm20/emoji),
[`Emot`](https://github.com/NeelShah18/emot) but I couldn't figure out how to successfully convert the emojis to text and replace it in the text sentence.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`emoji.demojize`](https://github.com/carpedm20/emoji/blob/434a2d788838f50648bd2b484d02f8fcbf892868/emoji/core.py#L180) takes an optional `delimiters=(":", ":")` parameter. Change it to `("", "")`

```py
import emoji
text = "game is on  "
emoji.demojize(text, delimiters=("", ""))  # 'game is on fire fire'
```

You'll need to install it with

```bash
pip install emoji
```

Comment: Thank you. Just an outside question Is it also possible to convert emoticons to words? you know something like :-) to smile etc. along with emojis.

Comment: Doesn't look like there's a library that can help you with that. You could open an issue on the `emoji` github, or you could hand roll your own by [looking at this list of emoticons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_emoticons) and writing a bunch of `text.replace("<3", "heart")` or something more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

To convert emoji to text in a complete pandas data frame column

```
import emoji
def extract_emojis(s):
    return ''.join((' '+c+' ') if c in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI['en'] else c for c in s)

tweets_df['text'] = tweets_df['text'].apply(lambda x: extract_emojis(x))
tweets_df['text'] = tweets_df['text'].apply(lambda x: emoji.demojize(x))
```