# Is it possible to do emojis sentiment analysis using textblob?

Tags: python, nlp, sentiment-analysis, textblob

I am running sentiment analysis on WhatsApp chats using textblob and the result is working on just text but I am getting neutral results on emojis.
Is there a way that textblob would see smiling emojis and return a positive result?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure `textblob` specializes on textual data. If you want to factor in the influence of an emoji on a text you can demojize (convert emoji into text) it with the help of an external library. Refer to a similar question regarding demojizing [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57580288/how-to-replace-emoji-to-word-in-a-text)